# Objective C: Is there a way to call a completion block for a method in another method?

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks, completionhandler

I have multiple `GET` API request methods that call a completion block when it finishes. Here is an example of one.

```
- (void)getUserInfo
    onSuccess:(void (^)(id))successBlock
    onFailure:(void (^)(NSError *))failureBlock {

    NSString *urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/user/", baseUrl];

    [manager GET:urlStr parameters:nil progress:nil
          success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {
              successBlock(responseObject);
          }
          failure:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, NSError *error) {
              failureBlock(error);
          }];
}
```

However, I noticed that I am repeating the manager `GET` request code in other methods. I want to create another method that handles all of the requests and remove the repetitive code. The URL seems to be the only thing that changes. However, there is one flaw. I need to call the `successBlock` to let the method know the request has finished.

Maybe I need to take another path altogether and do something different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can pass completion blocks around and then call them from your final method which handles all the get requests.  I usually make completion blocks that are going to be reused typedefs for brevity.  Here's an example of what I mean (I added a second example method that also passes through to the center `getRequestWithURLString:onSuccess:onFailure:` method):

#### LLFakeManager.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

typedef void (^_Nullable SuccessCompletionBlock)(id responseObject);
typedef void (^_Nullable FailureCompletionBlock)(NSError *error);

@interface LLFakeManager : NSObject
- (void)getUserInfoOnSuccess:(SuccessCompletionBlock)successBlock onFailure:(FailureCompletionBlock)failureBlock;
- (void)getBooksCheckedOutOnSuccess:(SuccessCompletionBlock)successBlock onFailure:(FailureCompletionBlock)failureBlock;
@end

NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END
```

#### LLFakeManager.m

```
#import "LLFakeManager.h"

@interface LLFakeManager()
- (void)getRequestWithURLString:(NSString *)urlString
                      onSuccess:(SuccessCompletionBlock)successBlock
                      onFailure:(FailureCompletionBlock)failureBlock;
@end

@implementation LLFakeManager

- (void)getUserInfoOnSuccess:(SuccessCompletionBlock)successBlock onFailure:(FailureCompletionBlock)failureBlock {
    NSString *urlStr = @"FakeUserUrlPath";
    [self getRequestWithURLString:urlStr onSuccess:successBlock onFailure:failureBlock];
}

- (void)getBooksCheckedOutOnSuccess:(SuccessCompletionBlock)successBlock onFailure:(FailureCompletionBlock)failureBlock {
    NSString *urlString = @"FakeBooksUrlPath";
    [self getRequestWithURLString:urlString onSuccess:successBlock onFailure:failureBlock];
}

// central method that will handle all the get requests
- (void)getRequestWithURLString:(NSString *)urlString
                      onSuccess:(SuccessCompletionBlock)successBlock
                      onFailure:(FailureCompletionBlock)failureBlock {
    // some fake implementation here to do your request, then use the completion block passed in from whatever other method
    if (successBlock) {
        successBlock(@"responseObjectPassedBackHere");
    }
}

@end
```

And an example of calling it:

```
LLFakeManager *manager = [[LLFakeManager alloc] init];
[manager getUserInfoOnSuccess:^(id  _Nonnull responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"Here's my response object = %@", responseObject);
} onFailure:^(NSError * _Nonnull error) {
    // no implementation but same idea
}];
```

Would produce this log:

```
Here's my response object = responseObjectPassedBackHere
```

This site: http://goshdarnblocksyntax.com is a handy list of block syntax which may also be helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks, but I have a question. What's the point of this NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN

Comment: Xcode should add this by default when creating new classes, it's just quick hand so you don't have to add nullability specifiers to each property/method -- it basically means everything is assumed to have the default specifier of _Nonnull/nonnull unless you otherwise specify using _Nullable/nullable

Comment: Nullability specifiers are helpful for catching cases where you're either not properly handing a scenario when nil is passed to a method, and allows Xcode to warn you when you're possibly passing nil to a method that requires a Nonnull parameter.  Within Xcode, these should be picked up by the analyzer when you use the Product Menu > Analyze

Comment: Okay, I have some parameters that can accept nil because it is optional. Should I mark them with _Nullable? Thanks for the fast response.

Comment: Yes, as you can see from my example code, I had marked the completion blocks as _Nullable because there may be some scenarios where they are unused,  but also notice that in the central method i'm checking for the existence of the successBlock to handle the scenario when nil get's passed in by the caller. i.e. if (successBlock)

Comment: Thanks for the help. This makes more sense now.

Answer (score 0):

The blocks -- if they have the same signature -- they can be passed along a chain of methods.  Your GET blocks carry an unneccesary first parameter. The `NSURLSessionTask *`, if it is to be returned at all, should be returned synchronously.  Moving that out of the block signature will allow you to standardize the blocks.

It's easier to say in code...

```
// changed this method name so it would compile

- (void)getUserInfoOnSuccess:(void (^)(id))successBlock
                   onFailure:(void (^)(NSError *))failureBlock {

    NSString *urlStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/user/", baseUrl];

   // two things: get the task as a return value (if you need it)
   // pass the blocks directly, without nesting them in new blocks
    NSURLSessionTask *task = [manager GET: urlStr
                               parameters: nil
                                 progress: nil
                                  success: successBlock
                                  failure: failureBlock];
    // do something with the task
}
```

To make this work, alter the GET method return type and block signatures...

```
- (NSURLSessionTask *)GET:(NSString *)url parameters:(id)params progress:(id)progress success:(void (^)(id))successBlock failure:(void (^)(NSError *))failureBlock {
    // return the session task created here
    return task
}
```